# Problema con ejecución asíncrona al cargar imágenes en canvas

Tags: nodejs, canvas

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, y actualmente, estoy teniendo un problema, el código es muy largo: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SB7XbbeP).

El problema está en la línea 61, al programa, a veces no le da tiempo cargar la imagen antes de hacer `resolve(c)` (en la línea 78), así que envía la imagen canvas sin el avatar (la imagen de la línea 61).

```
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 9, 90, 90);
}
img.src = buffer;
```

Este problema no pasa con imágenes [jpg](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/158341246635606016/110ce36df1742182dde28810f8cbe1fc.jpg?size=1024), pero también funciona con imágenes [gif](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/222715560876572672/a_665e681248174b842b72d3df07f53bea.gif?size=1024) (ambos enlaces son avatars diferentes que he probado). El programa muestra correctamente las imágenes. En el caso del ejemplo con la imagen gif, la aplicación envía la siguiente imagen (la cual es correcta):

[image: kotaruS]

Sin embargo, el problema está cuando se usan gifs más pesados, (como el que tengo actualmente en Discord): link [aquí](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/242043489611808769/a_59edf9e2b72c408c05ff9b7522d7ffc3.gif?size=1024).

Así que... supuse que era un problema de la ejecución asíncrona, ya que el programa está permitiendo la carga de imágenes gif ligeros. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esto puedo cargar mi avatar (el cual es un gif "pesado") de manera exitosa?

Ah, sin el `img.onload`, la aplicación mandaba el siguiente error: `Image given has not completed loading`.

> He actualizado el código, aunque sigue sin cargar correctamente el avatar, [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/irenipesab.js) (esta versión está comentada y es más limpia).

Comment: ¿Por qué haces uso de `await` en funciones donde no se devuelve una promesa? Por ejemplo, `await ctx.drawImage(...)` no tiene ninguna utilidad porque [`CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) no devuelve una promesa, es un método síncrono. Lo mismo para [`Buffer#concat`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength).

Comment: Para serte sincero, no tengo ni idea de dónde fue `Buffer` declarado. Sobre los `async/await` los puse con la vana esperanza de recibir un diferente resultado (no funcionan en métodos síncrono), aunque ya los he removido. [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/irenipesab.js). Resultados: [avatar1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/158341246635606016/f9ef53053cdc2ce28051dbfa4909348a.jpg?size=1024) > [canvas1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/256955011370713088/281563934236868619/file.jpg);

Comment: Segunda prueba: [avatar2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/242043489611808769/a_59edf9e2b72c408c05ff9b7522d7ffc3.gif?size=1024) > [canvas2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/256955011370713088/281563947629412353/file.jpg); el GIF "ligero" sigue mostrando el mismo resultado que puse arriba.

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué pasa en imágenes pesadas? ¿No se dibujan? ¿Qué pasa si usas `resolve` luego de pintar la imagen?

Comment: Intenté una cosa, puse el `resolve c;` para ver qué pasaba, sigue mandando la imagen en los mismos casos, sin embargo, al intentarlo con mi avatar (en el ultimo comentario que envié, revisa los enlaces "avatar2" y "canvas2"), simplemente... no hace nada. (He esperado más de 5 minutos por si acaso).

Comment: `img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 9, 90, 90); img.src = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    ctx.restore();
    resolve(c);
    }
   ` Trata de dejarlo asi.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si dibujas la imagen **dentro de una promesa**, es decir, dentro de una función separada que retorne una promesa luego de dibujar la imagen, de tal modo que puedas hacer uso de `await` en la promesa principal para que "espere" a que la imagen sea dibujada antes de resolver. Ejemplo: http://bit.ly/2l9MMky. Si no quieres hacer uso de `await` entonces llamar a `restore` y `resolve` en el `onload` debería tener el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Resolver luego de dibujarse la imagen
2. Envolver el dibujado en una función que retorne una promesa para "esperar por ella".

**Resolver desde la imagen**

Esta forma no merece mayor explicación. Lo único que hay que hacer es llamar a `restore` y `resolve` luego de dibujar la imagen:

```
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(this, 5, 9, 90, 90);
  ctx.restore();
  resolve(c);
}
```

**Dibujar la imagen en una promesa**

Ya que utilizas `async/await` en tu código, puedes modularizar un poco tu código para dibujar en una promesa, de modo que, en la promesa principal se "espere" a que se resuelva el dibujado antes de proceder a resolver.

```
function drawImage (data, ctx) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let image = new canvas.Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(this, 5, 9, 90, 90);
      resolve(); // aquí resolvemos el dibujo de la imagen
    }
    image.src = data;
  });
}
```

Y en la promesa principal:

```
await drawImage(Buffer.concat(buffers), ctx); // espera a que se dibuje
ctx.restore();
resolve(c);
```

Comment: El primero: Manda la imagen cuando el avatar ha sido cargado, pero cuando uso mi avatar (gif pesado, a pesar de que sólo pesa 1MB), no manda absolutamente nada (lo escribí en los comentarios). El segundo me devuelve esto: `TypeError: Image or Canvas expected`

Comment: Empiezo a pensar que es un problema del paquete que estoy usando (stream-to-array) para convertir una imagen de internet en un buffer para poder trabajarla en Canvas sin tener que descargarla, o de algún procedimiento para impedir que `img.onload` funcione.

Comment: Sin embargo... ha sido capaz de procesar mi [foto de perfil](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/267727088465739778/280740961795964928/unknown.png) a png.

Comment: ¿Podría ser que se tratase solo de imágenes gif? ¿Has tratado de cargar una imagen png/jpg de más de 1MB?

Comment: No tenía una imagen PNG/JPG que pesara +1MB, así que probé con dos gifs, uno de 1MB y otro de 2MB, ambos locales, cargados con `img.src = await fsp.readFileAsync("giphy.gif");`, y... muestra la [imagen](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/256955011370713088/281802352195796992/file.jpg) correctamente. Adjunto el [gif](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/256955011370713088/281802901268201472/giphy.gif) de 2MB. Entonces estoy enfrentándome a un problema, `Buffer.concat(streamToArray(request(url)));` no está funcionando como debería.

Comment: Mr Robot :D Quiero que ya empiece la tercera temporada ;). Al parecer el problema está allí. Podrías separar esa instrucción en tres para ver en qué punto falla. Me explico: `let imageStream = request(url); let imageArray = streamToArray(imageStream); let imageBuffer = Buffer.concat(imageArray);` e imprimir el resultado de cada instrucción. Quizás pueda deberse a permisos. Otra opción es convertir la imagen a base64.

Comment: De hecho, está en dos líneas diferentes. Lo he separado en una tercera pieza: `const thisAvatar = await request(url);`; `const buffers = await streamToArray(thisAvatar);`; `Buffer.concat(buffers);`. Sigue sin funcionar con mi foto de perfil.

Comment: Me refiero a que imprimas el resultado de cada expresión para que te cerciores que se está haciendo la operación y devolviendo lo esperado.

Comment: Imprimir, ¿en la consola? Añadí lo siguiente: `console.log(Buffer.concat(buffers));` devolvió: `<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 96 00 96 00 f7 67 00 e9 e9 ee 6d 4f 6c 55 3f 55 ff ff ff ff ee ee 22 11 33 33 22 44 b4 70 6e 49 2c 49 4c 4e 6b ff ff ee 6e 70 8d ce ... >` (con mi foto de perfil). Con una imagen válida: `<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0a 0c 14 0d 0c 0b 0b 0c 19 12 13 0f ... >`, pero vamos, básicamente lo mismo...

Comment: Adicionalmente, añadí la siguiente línea: `client.channels.get("256955011370713088").sendFile(Buffer.concat(buffers));`, y la aplicación mandó la [imagen](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/256955011370713088/281815077366005760/file.jpg). Aunque claro, [captura de pantalla](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/261464277196472320/281815616191463425/unknown.png). kek, me acabo de dar cuenta, la imagen, es en realidad un gif dentro del formato JPG... Entonces la solución debe ser usando el paquete `gm`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53764/discussion-between-guz-and-antonio-roman).

Answer (score 0):

si necesitas que la imagen este cargada antes de ejecutar una funcion, tienes que agrgarlo dentro de la funcion que ejecuta al terminar la carga. Puedes intentar

```
    img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 9, 90, 90);
      resolve(c);
    }
    img.src = Buffer.concat(buffers);
```

Comment: Eso fue de lo primero que intenté, y no funcionó.